# Intersection of two sets

Tags: java, set

Is easy way to get the intersection of two sets? 
I have:

```
    Set<Long> set1 = {1,2,3}
    Set<Long> set2 = {2,3,4}
```

And I looking or method like:

```
    Set<Long> intersection = new HashSet<>();
    intersection.intersect(set1, set2);
```

And intersection.toString() produce me set contains {2,3}

Comment: Use `set1.retainAll(set2)`

Comment: If you don't mind to use apache commons. Here you are: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection) util method is called intersection

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

Note that this will modify one of the collections so you might want to create a copy first.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method of [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
Set<String> s1;
Set<String> s2;
s1.retainAll(s2); // s1 now contains only elements in both sets
```

But, `retainAll`, will modify the content of `s1`. You should create a copy of `s1` and use `retainAll` on the copy

Avoid this by below,

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(s1); // use the copy constructor
mySet.retainAll(s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or to preserve the values:

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(set1);
intersection.retainAll(set2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `retainAll()` method is used to remove it's elements from a list that are not contained in the specified collection.

```
Set<Long> set1 = {1,2,3}
Set<Long> set2 = {2,3,4}    
set1.retainAll(set2);//finally prints 2,3
```